# _pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK

Tags: python, pickle

I got exceptions like **UnicodeDecodeError** raised when pickling (a list of) objects of EventFrame with a member *participants* that was an empty set.

```
class EventFrame:
    """Frame for an event"""
    def __init__(self, id=0):
        ...
        self.participants = set()
        ...
```

When it wasn't empty, there were no problems, so I first set *participants* to something and then pickled it. But during runtime it may happen that *participants* is emptied again.

So I tried to manually delete the object in this case. After that I dumped it again using pickle.

```
if len(frame.participants) == 0:
    frame_list.remove(frame)
```

That doesn't seem to be a good choice, because this **UnpicklingError** was raised:

```
....
frame_list.append (pickle.load(f))
_pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK
```

I don't know what it means and I couldn't find anything useful about it.

**Note** that this error is raised on loading the pickle file.

Here is the way I'm picklng and unpickling:

```
f = open("myfile", "r+b")
frame_list = []
while 1:
    try:
        frame_list.append (pickle.load(f))
        frame_list = sum(frame_list, [])
    except EOFError:
        break
f.close()
```

and dumping:

```
f = open("myfile", "r+b")
pickle.dump(frame_list, f)
f.close()
```

Comment: I have to delete the file and create it new, then dump the frame_list again. That works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error `_pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK` is raised because the offset of the file is not in the beginning.  The solution is to call `f.seek(0)` before loading the pickle.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error at first `_pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK`, but that was because I was using the class name in the module name. Once I removed it, it worked like a charm!

Comment: I am getting a similar error and I suspect it has something to do with my naming choices. Were you using *exactly* the same name? Could you share a bit more on that?