# could not find MARK

Tags: python, pickle

Here is my code in Python:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--use_model', type=str, help='model location', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--model_dim', type=int, help='model dimension of words', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
f = open(args.use_model, "rb")
f.seek(0)
trained_model = pickle.load(f)
```

I get `_pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK` error on last line.

In this question:

[_pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879096/pickle-unpicklingerror-could-not-find-mark)

it says that `f.seek(0)` solves the problem, but in my case it didn't.

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to the question please?

Comment: Is the file you're trying to read actually a pickled Python object?  Where did it come from?  Is it an empty file?

Comment: was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code of the underlining *[_pickle](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_pickle.c)* module (written in C), there is only one place where such error can appear:

```c
static Py_ssize_t
marker(UnpicklerObject *self)
{
    Py_ssize_t mark;

    if (self->num_marks < 1) {
        PickleState *st = _Pickle_GetGlobalState();
        PyErr_SetString(st->UnpicklingError, "could not find MARK");
        return -1;
    }
...
}
```

Underhood, the pickle module uses a mark stack for unpickling container objects, and `num_marks` indicates how many objects in it. By initialization of [Unpickler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_pickle.c#L1588) function, `num_marks` is set to 0 and then incremented when a new mark pushed onto the mark stack.

One of the possible ways to get this error is to change FRAME opcode (the value that indicates the start of a frame) or MARK opcode. Let's assume that we use protocol 4 (starting from this version pickle features binary framing), you can read more in [pep 3154](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3154/#framing). The idea is simple and straightforward - split all the content into chunks (frames) and mark the boundaries of every frame. Let's dive into it.

Consider this example:

```py
import pickle
data = {"fruits": ["apple", "banana", "pineapple"] }

with open("data.pickle", 'wb') as f:
    # Pickle the 'data' dictionary using the highest protocol available.
    pickle.dump(data, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Let's investigate a bit with [pickletools](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/pickletools.html#module-pickletools):

```
python -m pickletools data.pickle
    0: \x80 PROTO      5
    2: \x95 FRAME      46
   11: }    EMPTY_DICT
   12: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 0)
   13: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'fruits'
   21: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 1)
   22: ]    EMPTY_LIST
   23: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 2)
   24: (    MARK
   25: \x8c     SHORT_BINUNICODE 'apple'
   32: \x94     MEMOIZE    (as 3)
   33: \x8c     SHORT_BINUNICODE 'banana'
   41: \x94     MEMOIZE    (as 4)
   42: \x8c     SHORT_BINUNICODE 'pineapple'
   53: \x94     MEMOIZE    (as 5)
   54: e        APPENDS    (MARK at 24)
   55: s    SETITEM
   56: .    STOP
the highest protocol among opcodes = 4
```

Here FRAME (0x95) indicates the start position of a new frame and MARK ('(') the start of the container object, these values are specified by protocol (this is an implementation detail).

I would first take a look at the content of the pickle file, to summarise, the problem reasons can be:

1. The file is somehow corrupted.
2. The file pointer does not point to the start of a file, most likely can be fixed by `f.seek(0)`, see [_pickle.UnpicklingError: could not find MARK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879096/pickle-unpicklingerror-could-not-find-mark)
   ...

Found another cause? Feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same error.
A code which worked flawlessly has suddenly decided to throw this error.

A file corruption was the cause: CRLF has been replaced by LF by git.

I re-downloaded the file and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it was caused by using pandas read_pickle() on a file that was actually not a pickle file...