# Reuse file handle in python ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, whoosh

The background to my question is the following: I have a search index implemented in whoosh, and I want to get the rankings for a batch of queries. I want to speed this up by handling multiple queries at a time, using `ThreadPoolExecutor.map`.

In whoosh you have a `Searcher` object, which is (among other things) a wrapper that handles multiple open files and has an internal state where it currently points at which file. According to the [whoosh documentation](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/threads.html) you have to `use one Searcher per thread in your code`, but `if you can share one across multiple search requests, it’s a big performance win`. So my understanding is that every time the `ThreadPoolExecutor` opens a new thread it should be initialized with a `Searcher` object to the index, but when that thread is reused for another query it should keep that object instead of creating a new one per query.

My attempt was on the line of this:

```py
from whoosh import Index
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from typing import List

class MyExecutor:
  def __init__(self, whoosh_index: Index):
    self.searcher = index.searcher()

  def __call__(self, query):
    return self.searcher.search(query)


def query_batched(queries: List[str], whoosh_index: Index, num_threads: int):
  with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_threads) as pool:
    return pool.map(MyExecutor(whoosh_index), queries)
```

But this runs into an exception `UnpicklingError: could not find MARK` somewhere deep down in the whoosh code. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879096/pickle-unpicklingerror-could-not-find-mark) tells me that the error might be because it attempts to read a file which is not set to the beginning of a file. Does this mean that the code still uses only one `Searcher` across multiple threads, which is not thread-safe?

How can I fix the code so that each thread has its own `Searcher` object but reuses it every time it is called?

Comment: Reading the documentation I think it's saying to use one searcher per thread and within one thread the searcher should be used multiple times to get the caching performance benefits.